# Why is select with subselect returning no rows in condition so much slower?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a rather complicated select that looks like this.

```
select Columns 
  from TablesWithJoins 
 where MainColumn in (select AnotherColumn from OtherTablesWithJoins)
```

The problem is that the select usually ends in under 100 ms. ([sql plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkNpZXtiL))

[image]

When the subselect returns no rows than its execution time is much longer than if it had to return all the records without conditions. ([sql plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkV2GGtjL))

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Added version with `exists`. ([sql plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1Oi8mYiI))